# Viewing a published post in which its status is not open

Tags: channel-entries, categories, status

I have created a custom status which is titled "Completed". The application I am building allows for users to view courses they have attended or our attending in the future. All upcoming courses have a status of open and all courses that have been attended have a status of Completed.

I can only view posts that have a status of open, I am getting a white screen each time I try and view a post with the Completed status. If I change the status to open the post displays. Can anyone tell me if this is normal and is there a resolve for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is perfectly normal and expected behaviour.

To view content with status completed you need to add that to the "status" parameter in the channel entries tag, like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries status='open|Completed'}
```

More info here:
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#status